# How to point web part in item detail form to library based on metadata value from item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, document-library

Let's assume I have a list of projects with the fields "Project Title", and "Library", where "library" stores a value (e.g. URL or GUID) that identifies a library that is specific to each project. On my item detail form, I typically have one or more web parts that display related items for each project. I would like to add a web part that can "dynamically" point to the related library, per the value in the "Library" field.

**Any ideas on how to implement this functionality?**

Having trouble finding any relevant examples in my web searches so far...

Notes: Using SharePoint 2013, can use Designer but would like to know JavaScript options that might be available. Considered other alternatives including document sets, but they are not a good fit for the requirements. Each "Library" is used for work in process by different teams, so having the ability to use different structures and giving teams the ability to Sync their WIP with OneDrive (vs. syncing every other project document from a single library) is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it is possible to do this using an iFrame and jQuery.

Add a content editor web part to your DispForm.aspx page (assuming you are editing the default display page). Link this content editor web part to a script or text file.

An example of the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var fldValue = $('h3:contains("Project Library")').closest('td').next('td').text();
    var fldValueTrim = $.trim(fldValue);
    var libURL

    if (!fldValueTrim) {
        // field values is empty or whitespace-->404 type message
        //the following example is not functional; jquery will  vary depending on where you want to insert html
        $(some).jquery(). expresstion().html("<h1>We couldn't find your library.</h1>");

    } else {
        //show project library library
        libURL = "/sites/collection/subsite/etc/" + $.trim(fldValue);

        //Add a plachehodler for eventual iFrame
        //the following example is not functional; jquery will  vary depending on where you want to insert html
        $(some).jquery(). expresstion().html('<span>Custom instructions can go here</span><div id="queryResultContainer"/>');

        //Add iframes html content including src attribute to the placehodler div
        $('#queryResultContainer').html("<iframe id=myiFrame src='" + libURL
        + "?IsDlg=1' width=100% height=700px></iframe>");

        //hide the ribbon in the library appearing in the iframe
        $('#myiFrame').load(function(){
            $('#myiFrame').contents().find("#s4-ribbonrow").css('display', 'none');  
        });

    }

});

</script>
```